# Java GUI not displaying my file when opened

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, textarea, action

So I have a simple GUI that can only open text files and should just display them in a text area to be edited. I know my string contains the files contents since I can print it out, but when I try and add it to my text area, it does not show up. I was wondering if this was a problem of overlapping text areas but I can't seem to find the error.

The first part of my code just creates the GUI. The other part should open a file and fill the text area with it. Where exactly is the problem and how do I fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is part of my code which deals with creating the frames and panels:

```
public class MenuView extends JFrame {
  private JPanel centerPanel;
  private JPanel bottomPanel;
  private JMenuBar menuBar;
  private JMenu fileMenu;
  private JMenuItem openItem;
  private JMenuItem closeItem;
  private JButton setButton;
  private JTextField text;
  private JTextArea label;
  private JMenuItem fileNew;

    public MenuView(){
            super();
            setSize(500, 400);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setTitle("Menu Demo");

        //The center panel that will contain text
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label = new JTextArea(400,500);
        centerPanel.add(label);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //The bottom panel with the text field and button
        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        setButton = new JButton("Set Text");
        text = new JTextField();
        bottomPanel.add(setButton);
        bottomPanel.add(text);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Setting up the menu   
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileNew = new JMenu("New");
        openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        closeItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        fileMenu.add(openItem);
        fileMenu.add(closeItem);
        fileMenu.add(fileNew);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);   

        setButton.addActionListener(new ButtonCommand(label, text));
        closeItem.addActionListener(new QuitMenuCommand());
        openItem.addActionListener(new OpenMenuCommand(label));

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        MenuView v = new MenuView();
        v.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the code that deals with opening the files:

```
public class OpenMenuCommand implements ActionListener {

    private JTextArea theLabel;
    private JFileChooser fc;
    private String k = "";

    public OpenMenuCommand(JTextArea l){
        theLabel = l;
        theLabel.getParent();
        fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text file", "txt"));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();

        int returnValue = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(returnValue == fc.APPROVE_OPTION){
            theLabel.removeAll();
            File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
            try{
                BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                String in = inFile.readLine();
                while(in != null){
                    k = k + in;
                    in = inFile.readLine();
                }
                System.out.println(k);  
                theLabel.setText(k);
                inFile.close();
                theLabel.setVisible(true);
            }catch(FileNotFoundException exc){
                //Should never trigger
            }catch(IOException exc){
                theLabel.setText("Error reading in file.");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting one. Can you post a screenshot? Also, if you think it might be overlapping JTextFields, then try initializing the text field with some text already in it, just for testing. If the initial text shows up, then I'm guessing you probably don't have an overlapping issue.

Comment: @normalocity: it has nothing to do with overlapping but rather all to do with adding a very large component (JTextArea) to a small FlowLayout-using container.

Comment: that is not the way to load data into a text area. Just use the JTextArea.read(...) method. Its one line of code. No need for looping logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stuff is being added to the JTextArea but you're not seeing due the size of the JTextArea.  It's actually a friggin' big JTextArea:

```
label = new JTextArea(400, 500);
```

And by adding the huge JTextArea to a FlowLayout-using JPanel much of it is off the screen. 
To see what I mean, add this to your actionPerformed method:

```
System.out.println(theLabel.getBounds());
```

You'll see that the width and height are tremendous, and what's more, the left side is a large negative number.

Solution: Make your JTextArea more reasonable size (see in the API what these numbers mean -- row and column, not points) and add it to a JScrollPane and then add that BorderLayout.CENTER to a BorderLayout using container.

For example, the small GUI SSCCE shows your JTextArea in a FlowLayout using JPanel on the left and my JTextArea inside of a JScrollPane on the right:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MenuViewSSCCE {
   private static final Dimension APP_SIZE = new Dimension(500, 400);

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JTextArea label = new JTextArea(400, 500); // friggin big!
      JTextArea label2 = new JTextArea(400, 500); // friggin big!
      label.setText("Look at how big this JTextArea is!");
      label2.setText("Look at how big this JTextArea is!");

      JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
      centerPanel.setPreferredSize(APP_SIZE);
      centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // this line is redundant 
      centerPanel.add(label);

      JScrollPane myScrollpane = new JScrollPane(label2);
      myScrollpane.setPreferredSize(APP_SIZE);

      JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
      gridPanel.add(centerPanel);
      gridPanel.add(myScrollpane);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Your code on left, mine on right");
      frame.getContentPane().add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought the size was supposed to be in pixels, not columns and rows and was getting frustrated over that so much.